# Why are my labels disappearing when executing this code?

Tags: iphone

I'm just beginning in iOS development, and am trying to make a simple app that takes time input in EST and then outputs PST and CST. I've gotten the View Controller setup, but my function for actually displaying the times only makes my labels disappear. Here's that function's code.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPress {
NSDateFormatter *date = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[date setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
[date setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[date setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

NSDate *estTime = [date dateFromString:self.estText.text];
[date setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a zzz"];
self.pstText.text = [date stringFromDate:estTime];

[date setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"CST"]];

self.cstText.text = [date stringFromDate:estTime];
```

}

Comment: is self.estText.text empty ? or what text ist in there ? because if parsing with dateFromString fails all the string gonna be empty

Comment: No, that should be taking the input from a text field when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try do see if you can hardcode any text when pressing the button, ie

```
self.pstText.text = @"Does this work?";
```

You could also try to log out your date string

```
NSLog(@"Date is: %@", [date stringFromDate:estTime]);
```

To verify that you got something else than an empty string ;-)

Comment: Also Making sure label property textColor, backgroundColor are set properly so that label is not transparent.

Comment: Hard coding text in does work, but it doesn't look like logging the string out works.

Comment: Then i believe your date formatting is returning an empty string :-)

Comment: Well apparently the problem was the way I was inputting into my text field. It works with a space between the time and am or pm, like 3:30 pm, but not with 3:30pm.